# I want the first div to fade out and then second to fade by using a dummy submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the `<div id="fadeout">` to fadeout when the submit button is clicked, and then the `<div id="fadein">` to fade in to replace the previous div. Not having much luck at all.

I've tried several methods but just can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated

```
    <html>
    <title>Break Calculator</title>

<head>
<style>
body {
    background: #0e415f;
    min-width:55em;
    max-width:200em;
    font-family: Omnes, Myriad Pro, arial, Helvetica;
    color: #f1a400;}

.salary_div {
    width: 12em;
    margin: 0 auto;}

.salary_input{
    width: 6em;
    height: 1.2em;
    font-size: 2em;}

.submit_div {
    width: 8em; 
    margin: 1em auto;}  

.header {
    width: 55em;
    margin: 0 auto;}

.clock {
    border: .1em solid #f1a400 double;
    border-radius: .1em;
    border-style: double;
    width: 3.5em;
    margin: 20 auto;    

    font-size: 10em;
    text-align:center;}

.money {
    border: .1em solid #f1a400 double;
    border-radius: .1em;
    border-style: double;
    width: 3.5em;
    margin: 20 auto;

    font-size: 10em;
    text-align:center;}

.buttons {
    width: 24.5em; 
    margin: 1em auto;}  

.button_style{
    height:2.5em;
    width:6em;
    font-size:1.2em;
    margin: 0 .3em;
    background: #f1a400;
    border-radius: .4em;
    border: 0;}
</style>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var salary;
var seconds=-1.0; /* To start clock at 0 seconds */
var min=0;
var time;
var secPay;
var timerPay = 0; 


function getSalary() {
        var salaryAm = document.getElementById("salaries");
        salary = salaryAm.value;
        secPay = salary/(52*40*60*60); // Weeks * Hours * Minutes * Seconds *// 
        }
function timer(){
        seconds++;       

        if(seconds>59){
                min++;
                document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML=padTimer(min);
                seconds=0;}

        document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML=padTimer(seconds);    
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML=parseFloat(secPay*timerPay++).toFixed(2);
        };

function padTimer(x) {
    if (x<=9) { x = ("0"+x); }
    return x;}

function start(){
    if (getSalary()) {
        alert("please check input");
    } else {
        time=setInterval(timer, 1000);
        timer();}
  };

function pause() { 
    clearInterval(time);
    seconds--;
    timerPay--;};

function reset(){
    seconds=-1.0;
    timerPay=0;
    time=0;
    if (min !=0){
        min=0;}
    };

</script>
</head>

<body>


    <div class="header"><img src="breakcalc.png"></div>
<div id="fadeout">
    <div class="salary_div">
        <input id="salaries" type="text" class="salary_input">
    </div>

    <div class="submit_div">
        <a id="submit"><button class="button_style">Submit</button></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="fadein">
    <div class="clock" id="slideout">
        <span id="mins" >00</span>:<span id="secs">00</span>
    </div>

    <div class="money">
        <span>$ </span><span id="money">0.00</span>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
        <a href="#" id="button" onclick="start()" ondblclick="return false;"><button class="button_style">Start</button></a>
        <a href="#" id="button" onclick="pause()"><button class="button_style">Stop</button></a>
        <a href="#" id="button" onclick="reset()"><button class="button_style">Reset</button></a>
    </div>
</div>  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you want the 2nd to fade in AFTER or DURING the 1st is fading out?

Answer (score 1):

Add this into your script tags:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fadein").hide();
    $("#submit button").click(function() {
        $("#fadeout").fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $("#fadein").fadeIn("slow");
        });
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rX2SF/1/)

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? No one else pointed out that he needs to hide the div he wants to "fade in", otherwise it won't fade in.

Comment: No reason that I could see... +1

Comment: Also note that the original post didn't have jQuery loaded (just jQuery migrate). the OP will want to include jQuery for this answer (or any of these answers) to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this task easier using jQuery's fadeIn and fadeOut functions. See http://jsfiddle.net/BpnVQ/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $("#one").fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $("#two").fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the jquery library you're using - the one before wasn't resolving for me.
Also, I added the call to ready and removed the nesting of `<button> in <a>.`

```
<html>
        <title>Break Calculator</title>
    <head>
    <style>
    body {
        background: #0e415f;
        min-width:55em;
        max-width:200em;
        font-family: Omnes, Myriad Pro, arial, Helvetica;
        color: #f1a400;}

    .salary_div {
        width: 12em;
        margin: 0 auto;}

    .salary_input{
        width: 6em;
        height: 1.2em;
        font-size: 2em;}

    .submit_div {
        width: 8em; 
        margin: 1em auto;}  

    .header {
        width: 55em;
        margin: 0 auto;}

    .clock {
        border: .1em solid #f1a400 double;
        border-radius: .1em;
        border-style: double;
        width: 3.5em;
        margin: 20 auto;    

        font-size: 10em;
        text-align:center;}

    .money {
        border: .1em solid #f1a400 double;
        border-radius: .1em;
        border-style: double;
        width: 3.5em;
        margin: 20 auto;

        font-size: 10em;
        text-align:center;}

    .buttons {
        width: 24.5em; 
        margin: 1em auto;}  

    .button_style{
        height:2.5em;
        width:6em;
        font-size:1.2em;
        margin: 0 .3em;
        background: #f1a400;
        border-radius: .4em;
        border: 0;}
    </style>


    <script src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var salary;
    var seconds=-1.0; /* To start clock at 0 seconds */
    var min=0;
    var time;
    var secPay;
    var timerPay = 0; 


    function getSalary() {
            var salaryAm = document.getElementById("salaries");
            salary = salaryAm.value;
            secPay = salary/(52*40*60*60); // Weeks * Hours * Minutes * Seconds *// 
            }
    function timer(){
            seconds++;       

            if(seconds>59){
                    min++;
                    document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML=padTimer(min);
                    seconds=0;}

            document.getElementById("secs").innerHTML=padTimer(seconds);    
            document.getElementById("money").innerHTML=parseFloat(secPay*timerPay++).toFixed(2);
            };

    function padTimer(x) {
        if (x<=9) { x = ("0"+x); }
        return x;}

    function start(){
        if (getSalary()) {
            alert("please check input");
        } else {
            time=setInterval(timer, 1000);
            timer();}
      };

    function pause() { 
        clearInterval(time);
        seconds--;
        timerPay--;};

    function reset(){
        seconds=-1.0;
        timerPay=0;
        time=0;
        if (min !=0){
            min=0;}
        };

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
        $("#fadein").hide();
            $("#submit").click(function()
            {
                $("#fadeout").hide(300);
                $("#fadein").show(300);
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>


        <div class="header"><img src="breakcalc.png"></div>
    <div id="fadeout">
        <div class="salary_div">
            <input id="salaries" type="text" class="salary_input">
        </div>

        <div class="submit_div">
            <button id="submit" class="button_style">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="fadein">
        <div class="clock" id="slideout">
            <span id="mins" >00</span>:<span id="secs">00</span>
        </div>

        <div class="money">
            <span>$ </span><span id="money">0.00</span>
        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <a href="#" id="button" onclick="start()" ondblclick="return false;"><button class="button_style">Start</button></a>
            <a href="#" id="button" onclick="pause()"><button class="button_style">Stop</button></a>
            <a href="#" id="button" onclick="reset()"><button class="button_style">Reset</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>  
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

placing

```
$(document).on("click", ".submit_div", function() {
    $("#fadeout").fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $("#fadein").fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

in your script, should make that happen.

Comment: if you include `jquery`, why dont you use it?